# Static variables data saved between program runs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static

I'm having an issue where my static variables are being saved between plays in my unity editor. No code is saving them to a file and then loading them upon start.

```
public static class PlayerStatus
{
  static int maxStamina = 100;
  static int stamina = 100;

  public static int Stamina { get { return stamina; } }
  public static int MaxStamina { get { return maxStamina; } }

  public static void AdjustStamina(int amount)
  {
    stamina += amount;
    if(stamina <= 0)
        fainted = true;
  }
}

public class Stamina: Monobehavior
{
  private void Start()
  {
    slider.value = (float)PlayerStatus.Stamina / (float)PlayerStatus.MaxStamina;
  }
}
```

Here is a gif of the issue in action. At the start I purposely use up some of my stamina. This is shown in a stamina bar in the bottom-right. I then click the play button in the editor. Then I press the play button again to start the program. The stamina bar shows the previous amount. I then use up some more stamina to make sure it isn't a visual issue.

[Static Variable Issue Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH7ST.gif)

Is this just a lack of understanding what a static variable does? I would've thought it would reset to 100 with every run of the editor. Is it being saved to memory and then erased when unity closes or my computer shuts down? Thanks.

Comment: Should be fine, unless you're calling it some editor script. Really, I wouldn't recommend using statics for data, spawn a singleton if you want it accessible from anywhere.

Comment: The issue is that the problem i'm having is true of any static variable in non-static classes. I'm trying to understand how static classes and variable interact with the Unity editor as they seem to be running even when the editor is not running a game.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you've disabled "reload domain/scene" by enabling Project settings - Editor - Enter Play Mode Options. This is usually done to enable quicker play in the editor.

All explained here, including workaround for statics[Unity: DomainReloading](https://docs.unity3d.com/es/2019.4/Manual/DomainReloading.html)